# Intuition of the proof on the minimality of $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I know that this is fairly standard and that there are many ways to do this. I want to understand here what is happening intuitively in [Stromberg's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1470425440) proof of **Theorem (1.55)**.

The proof is as follows.

> Assume $\mathbb{N}$ is finite. Since $\mathbb{N}\neq \lbrace\rbrace$, there is a smallest $n$ such that $\mathbb{N}\sim \lbrace k\in\mathbb{N}: 1\leq k\leq n \rbrace$. Let $f:\lbrace k\in\mathbb{N}: 1\leq k\leq n \rbrace \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be one-to-one and onto. Now define  $g:\lbrace k\in\mathbb{N}: 1\leq k\leq n-1 \rbrace \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ by the rule \begin{equation}g(k) =\begin{cases} f(k),& \operatorname{if}  f(k)<f(n)\\ f(k)-1,& \operatorname{if} f(k)>f(n).\end{cases}\end{equation}
>   Then $g$ is one to one and onto $\mathbb{N}$. This contradicts the minimality of $\mathbb{N}$.

Formally, I understand all the arguments. Since $f$ is one to one and onto, one can check that $g$ is also one to one and onto. If this is the case, in particular the case that I don't understand, being $g$ onto means that for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there is a $k\in \lbrace k\in\mathbb{N}: 1\leq k\leq n-1 \rbrace$ such that $g(k)=n$.

But what I can't see is how to propose a particular $f$ such that for, say, $n\in\mathbb{N},\;g(k)=n$. There's simply "not enough" elements in the domain of $g$ to do this (but it should be, since $g$ is onto).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick $m\in\mathbb N$. We must find $k$ with $1\le k\le n-1$ such that $g(k)=m$.

First, we are given that $f$ is onto, so there is $s$ with $1\le s\le n$ such that $f(s)=m$. If $m<f(n)$, then we could let $k=s$, so that $g(k)=g(s)=f(s)=m$ by definition of $g$, *as long as* $s<n$ (because then $1\le s\le n-1$ and $s$ is in the domain of $g$). Now, $s\ne n$ because $f(s)<f(n)$, so we are done with this case.

So we are left with the situation where $m\ge f(n)$. Since $f$ is onto, there is a $t$ with $1\le t\le n$ such that $f(t)=m+1$ (and note that $m+1>f(n)$). If $t<n$ then, by definition of $g$, we can take $k=t$: $g(k)=g(t)=f(t)-1=m$. Again, $t=n$ is impossible, this time because $f(t)>f(n)$.

Comment: (Of course, the argument is a bit strange. The thing to remember is that we are trying to see that the formal definitions we are working with match reasonably well our intuitions. Intuitively, everything is obvious and there could be no $f$ to begin with. Formally, that is also the case, but our argument can no longer appeal to our intuitive understanding of finitude or infinity.)

Comment: Yep, this is exactly why this appears involved.